# How to convert items of NSArray to utf16 (char16_t)?

Tags: nsarray, objective-c++, utf-16

I have a function that gets all contents of directory whether files or directories and I am using `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` to collect the content of a directory then I save the names of files/directories into a container called `contentsStore` which accepts key&value items of UTF-16 string `char16_t`. look at the following code to make your vision clear:

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_dirPath error:nil];
for(unsigned int i= 0; i< [dirContents count]; i++){
    if(isDir){
        // `contentsStore` is key&value container that accepts utf-16 string (char16_t)
        contentsStore.Add([[dirContents objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], "directory");
    } else {
        contentsStore.Add([[dirContents objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String], "file");
    }
}
```

Note that I don't post the entire code because it's big but I just added the important parts that related to the problem. Also, I am using Objective-C just as a bridge to achieve my goal to use Cocoa in macOS but the main language that I use is C++, so, the entire code is a combination of C++/Objective-C.

**How to make the `objectAtIndex` method to output the item's content as UTF-16 `char16_t`?**

Comment: if you don't need `fileSystemRepresentationWithPath`: `objectAtIndex:` returns a `NSString`. Have you tried the methods in the "Getting Characters and Bytes" and "Getting C Strings" sections of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc)?

Answer (score 0):

the following will give you an idea. The `[Filemanager defaultmanager]` is actually supporting your task. You can convert the path to C-string and convert then into string of `char16_t` aka `basic_string<char16_t>`.

```
NSString *_dirPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] init];
NSArray *dirContents = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_dirPath error:&error];

if (!error && dirContents.count ) {

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [dirContents count]; i++){
        NSString *path = [dirContents objectAtIndex:i];
        BOOL isDir;
        std::string usingkey = "file";

        if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
            usingkey = "directory";
        }
        
        const char *fileRepresentation = [manager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:path];

        // function declared below..
        std::u16string char16string = to_utf16(fileRepresentation);

        // and use it to store your C++ storageObject, value&key pair
        // don't know of what datatype is usingkey in your source 
        // just assumed std::string 
        contentsStore.Add(char16string, usingkey);

    }
}
```

you will have to include the following in your `.mm` implementation

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>

@implementation Yourclassname 

//std::u16string is same as basic_string<char16_t>
std::u16string to_utf16( std::string str )
{ return std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t >{}.from_bytes(str); }

@end
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to tell you that I am using Objective-C just as a bridge to achieve my goal to use Cocoa in macOS but the main language that I use is C++, so, the entire code is a combination of C++/Objective-C.

Comment: even better. but that does'nt make the answer less valid i hope. fileRepresentation is made for that.. it explicitly converts to C-Strings, aka const char* meant for that case you have. Was just using `@(const char*yours)` which packs the c-string again as NSString to store it in the nsdicts in nsarray. Should be easy to adopt to C/C++ because const char* is all the same there.

Comment: The target encoding that I want to access is UTF-16 specifically the data type `char16_t` because the container `contentStore` just accepts that encoding.

Comment: consider when using objective-C you can use C in scope directly. When you want to integrate C++ you may run Objective-C++ and the solutions for the explicit conversion uint_least16_t which is char16_t is different then.

Comment: I already use objective-C++ the source file extension is `.mm`. is it possible to ouput this `NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; ` to char16_t?

Comment: uchar.h which would support mbrtoc16() is not existing on apple and the functions offered elsewhere don't support char16_t either, maybe wchar_t, but thats too far away. In other words developers are forced to rewrite their code because char16_t is not supported out of the box, after a little research in SO. So check the edited answer, maybe thats working for you as expected. let me know